# Robolectric won't run with SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(KEYGEN_ALGORITHM)

Tags: android, robolectric

Robolectric throws errors on every test I start with the logs:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid environment
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:240)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:177)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid environment
    at com.android.vending.licensing.AESObfuscator.<init>(AESObfuscator.java:68)
    at com.myproject.ApplicationClass.onCreate(ApplicationClass.java:65)
    at org.robolectric.internal.ParallelUniverse.setUpApplicationState(ParallelUniverse.java:164)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.setUpApplicationState(RobolectricTestRunner.java:430)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:236)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBEWITHSHAAND256BITAES-CBC-BC SecretKeyFactory not available
    at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.<init>(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(DashoA13*..)
    at com.android.vending.licensing.AESObfuscator.<init>(AESObfuscator.java:57)
    ... 20 more
```

It fails at line:

```
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWITHSHAAND256BITAES-CBC-BC");
```

I will appreciate any suggestions. The Java SDK is 1.6 (for test an android project). android.jar for the test project is from 18 android version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that when you run the test, you don't seem to have an implementation for that algorithm. I'm guessing from your question that this code works ok on the Android device and only fails on tests. If that's the case, it might be that Android includes some implementation, but when you run the Robolectric tests (which run on the JVM, not on the Android device) you don't have one anymore.

Try getting [bouncy castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html), and make sure to get the correct release for the JDK version you have (which could be different from 6, as Robo tests will happily build and run with newer version of Java as well, even if Android lives in Java 6 times). Add that to your classpath for the robolectric tests only, as there doesn't seem to be any need to distribute it with the app and then try again.

Comment: thank you for the answer. It's correct one. Yes, everything works on Android device as failed on test. Getting bouncy castle fixed the problem.

Comment: Glad that worked! Make sure the scope for your bouncy castle jar is for test only, as there is no need to ship it with the app (and if you did decide that you needed to ship it with the app, there is an android-specific fork of it).